# webdriverio selenium-webdriver for nodejs, issue with iframe

Tags: mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I'm working on automation of website, which has iframes within iframes, need to way to identify using webdriverio

I'm trying with browser.frame(); It's not working for me.

Can anybody give inputs here ?

Thanks,
Audi

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine how many iframes are on the page. The use browser.frame(0) for the first frame...browser.frame(n) for the nth frame